# Not all files added to Git repository

Tags: git, repository

I've created repo, with standard commands

```
git init
git add .
git remote add origin ssh://trololo.lo/~/git_rep.git
git commit -a -m "trololo"
git push origin master
```

After that i've created empty repo on another machine, pulled origin. Some files are missing, any idea why and what I should do?

Comment: Are you sure that you added, committed, and pushed every time you added/made changes to files?

Comment: are the missing files part of the .gitignore file?

Comment: or .git/info/exclude or `core.excludesfile`

Comment: @Recursed: as a sidenote, as far as tracked files changes are concerned, him issuing `git commit -a` would be perfectly safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you do the `commit`, run `git status` and make sure that you're committing what you think you're committing.  If you can run `git status` *after* the commit and get anything other than a `working directory clean` message, then there was something that you forgot to `add` before committing.

Answer (score 0):

```
git add -A
git commit -m "message here"
git push origin master
```

Comment: The key part to use "git add -A" instead of "git add ."